# Using Parse (Android) with RxJava

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, rx-java, rx-android

**Background**

I'm using the Clean architecture in my android app. My domain and data layer are heavily RxJava-based (RxAndroid).I'm also using [Parse(BaaS)](https://parse.com/).

**Question**

I know that the Android Parse SDK is doing a lot of work under the hood like caching and encrypting data. Is it really stable to use its synchronous calls with RxJava's Schedulers?
I know that Retrofit works well with RxJava. Should I drop the Parse SDK and use their REST API instead ?

Help me, I'll give you a cookie !

Comment: I assume the exception is thrown during a later api call? can you detail how/where the exception is thrown?

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question. I'm not using the parse sdk anymore. I chose their REST API because there's a possibility to have my own api in the future. When that happens, I'll only change the api urls instead of the whole code in the data layer. Plus, code is much cleaner with Retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the Android Parse SDK is doing a lot of work under the
>   hood like caching and encrypting data. Is it really stable to use its
>   synchronous calls with RxJava's Schedulers?

Parse has plenty of android SDK samples on git etc. If your Rx is friendly with Curl maybe you could also look at REST api from parse.

Otherwise, in the 'Rx' request/response circuit you should try to expose the http traffic ( headers  that contain parseAppId, and parseUserToken )

The token mention in the [exception](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide)

scroll down till 'handling invalid session token'.....

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using the parse sdk anymore. I chose their REST API because there's a possibility to have my own api in the future. When that happens, I'll only change the api urls instead of the whole code in the data layer. Plus, code is much cleaner with Retrofit.